# using class Viewer from Forge Viewer Component (ng2-adsk-forge-viewer) Angular

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im using Forge Viewer Component from (ng2-adsk-forge-viewer lib). I want to use the current viewer class (Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D) for another component, so another component can do some function impact to model. But i dont know the way to get that class ? anybody using that component can help me?
Appreciate any comments.

Paxton.

Answer (score 0):

The [ng2-adsk-forge-viewer](https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer) is made by the 3rd party. It's not maintained by Autodesk. Please check the following link for the source code:

https://github.com/theNBS/ng2-adsk-forge-viewer